# Generating seamless matplotlib contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I'm using matplotlib and Python to generate a contour plot that I would like to make seamless across the X axis (meaning the contour regions will wrap at the right edge and align with the values from the left edge to create continuous regions). What is the best way to approach something like this?